# Power Pivot - DAX - Show zero instead of blank not working

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I am banging my head against the wall here.

I have this measure:

```
If((SUM(Query1[BalanceSaldo]))=BLANK();0;SUM(Query1[BalanceSaldo]))
```

I have also tried:

```
If(ISBLANK(SUM(Query1[BalanceSaldo]));0;SUM(Query1[BalanceSaldo]))
```

but with no avail - neither of the measures is replacing blanks with zeros.

The measure SUM() is basically summing up balances in financial accounts. In the Power Pivot table I have account names and categories showing in the rows and fiscal periods (2019 and 2020) showing on the columns.

My goal with this measure is to make the Pivot Table show 0 for year 2019 column in case there is only balance for a given row in 2020 and not in 2019... and vice versa.

I would use this measure further to give me differences between year columns (i noticed it does not make calculations when the other column is blank so that is why I am aiming for the zero value to fill in the blanks for me).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use

```
= SUM ( Query1[BalanceSaldo] ) + 0
```

Comment: Thank you but the blanks remain. This does not change the blanks in a column to zeros.

Comment: I created another measure: `ISBLANK(SUM(Query1[BalanceSaldo]))`. This is also blank in the same "cells" in the Pivot Table to where I tried to create the zeros...

Comment: I experimented some more. Assuming I have balance on an account for 2019 and not for 2020. Then the pivot table would show blank on 2020 and my difference calculation also subsequently fails. However, I can do a work-around by adding one row of data to the source table where year 2020 balance for this specific account is zero (0). Just by adding this zero row to the data source makes everything right. I am now thinking that is really so that I need to create dummy table with 0 balance for each account for 2019 and 2020?